# Metodos y pasar parametros

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Cree una aplicacion en java con netbeans y mysql para manejar una jugueteria, la aplicacion esta andando basicamente cumple con la mayoria de los requisitos, como mis conocimientos de java son muy basicos estoy queriendo mejorarla, asi tambien voy aprendiendo.
Pego una imagen
[image: Pantalla principal de la aplicacion]

Y cada boton imprime un informe segun la seleccion del combo box aca pego el codigo, de uno de los botones andando, sin mover el codigo a la clase impresion.

```
private void jButton_JugueProvActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

        int juguprov;
        Document documento = new Document();
        juguprov = cmb_JugProv.getSelectedIndex();

        try {
            String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/Reporte_JugProv.pdf"));

            com.itextpdf.text.Image header = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance("src/images/header.png");
            header.scaleToFit(650, 1000);
            header.setAlignment(Chunk.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph();
            parrafo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            parrafo.add("Informe creado para  © \n\n");
            parrafo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Tahoma", 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY));
            parrafo.add("Juguetes segun proveedor \n\n");

            documento.open();
            documento.add(header);
documento.add(parrafo);

            PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(7);
            tabla.setWidths(new int[]{20, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60});
            tabla.setWidthPercentage(100f);
            tabla.addCell("ID");
            tabla.addCell("Nombre Juguete");
            tabla.addCell("Precio");
            tabla.addCell("Tipo de juguete");
            tabla.addCell("Costo de fabricacion");
            tabla.addCell("Proveedor");
            tabla.addCell("Stock");

            try {
                Connection cn2 = Conexion.conectar();;
                PreparedStatement pst = cn2.prepareStatement("select id_juguetes, nombre, Precio, Tipo, Costo, "
                        + "proveedor.nombre_prov, Stock from juguetes, proveedor WHERE"
                        + " juguetes.Proveedor = proveedor.id_proveedor && '" + juguprov + "' = proveedor.id_proveedor");

                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Esto esta funcionando, ahora estoy queriendo mejorar la estructura de la aplicacion y como esta escrita.
Por esto estoy tratando de poner todo el codigo de cada opcion de impresion en una clase y despues llamarla atravez de un metodo.

Este es codigo que agrego en la clase impresion.

```
 public void ReporteVenJar() {

        Capturista ob = new Capturista();
        int compjard = ob.cmb();

        Document documento = new Document();

        try {

            String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");

            PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/Reporte_Compras " + ob.cmb() + ".pdf"));

            com.itextpdf.text.Image header = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance("src/images/header.png");
            header.scaleToFit(550, 1000);
            header.setAlignment(Chunk.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph();
            parrafo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            parrafo.add("Informe creado para  © \n\n");
            parrafo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Tahoma", 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY));
            parrafo.add("Ventas Registradas para el Jardin  \n\n");

            documento.open();
            documento.add(header);
```

Este es el codigo del boton en la clase capturista

```
    private void jButton_VentasJardActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        cmb();
        ImpresionPdf RepVenJar = new ImpresionPdf();
        RepVenJar.ReporteVenJar();
    }
```

Aca donde creo el metodo cmb()

```
public class Capturista extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String user, nombre_usuario;
    int sesion_usuario;

    public int cmb() {
        int cmb_pr;
        cmb_pr = cmb_CompJard.getSelectedIndex();
        return cmb_pr;
    }

    public Capturista() {
        initComponents();
        user = Login.user;
        sesion_usuario = Administrador.sesion_usuario;
```

El problema que tengo es que no me pasa el parametro a la clase impresionpdf entonces me imprime el informe vacio.
Seguramente tengo algun error de conceptos como soy nuevo en java no los tengo muy claros.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si  deseas pasar un parametro a la clase puedes realizarlo en el constructor o si únicamente lo deseas usar en un método puedes modificar el método para que reciba este parametro.

```
public void ReporteVenJar(int compjard) {

       // Capturista ob = new Capturista();
       // int compjard = ob.cmb();

         ...
         ...
         ...
}
```

Al modificar tu método ahora puedes enviar el valor en el método:

```
   private void jButton_VentasJardActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        //cmb();
        ImpresionPdf RepVenJar = new ImpresionPdf();        
        RepVenJar.ReporteVenJar(cmb());
    }
```